# Why is GitHub creating nonsense commits, here?

Tags: git, github, commit, line-endings

I cloned a friend's project. I haven't done any modifications and I already have tons uncommitted changes for all project files! For each file, it's as if I simply cut and paste all the contents, but I never did this, and even if I did it, there are no changes.

I tried to sync, but the uncommitted changes stay here forever anyway, so it makes tons of conflicts because, each time I push my changes, I also change all project files.

An exemple of these nonsense commits:

```
- Azerty
- Hello
- Codes
+ Azerty
+ Hello
+ Codes
```

Git always does this to all the code in all the tracked files; even after a sync, the uncommited changes appear again.

How to fix it? Why it this happening?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134066/git-diff-command-showing-entire-file-is-modified-instead-of-showing-modified-sma

Comment: Check the following things in the files in question: a) Encoding (Unix/Windows), b) Line Endings (LF or CRLF), c) Whitespace (in case your editor automatically changes these).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Mac: `git config --global core.autocrlf input`

Windows: `git config --global core.autocrlf true`

Linux: `git config --global core.autocrlf input`